# Android commands in the terminal

Tags: android, macos, terminal, adb

I want to use some android commands like the adb and avd commands in my terminal. I also add a ~/.profile file with the export commands like:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Users/me/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools
```

Befor I want to use these commands , I type `source ~/.profile` but when I use for example adb devices I get `Command not found`... I search for a while but the only solution I get is to go in my android platform-tools directory and type `./adb` to use the commands.